# ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence in python package anastruct

Tags: python

How to fix this Value error. i am using anasruct python package. When we using reaction force this value error came. axial, bending, deflection forces working. Can you please help me. show_reaction_force(show=True) is working when we did not used load combinations.

```
from anastruct.fem.system import SystemElements
from anastruct.fem.util.load import LoadCase, LoadCombination
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# importing system elements
ss = SystemElements(EA=14000, EI=5.36)
ss.add_element(location=[[0, 0], [6, 0]])
ss.discretize(n=6)
# Supports to elements
ss.add_support_fixed(node_id=1)
ss.add_support_fixed(node_id=7)
# apply loads
lc_dead = LoadCase('dead')
lc_dead.q_load(q=-10, element_id=2)
lc_dead.point_load(Fx=30, Fy=-50, node_id=2)
# apply load combination
combination1 = LoadCombination('SLS')
combination1.add_load_case(lc_dead, factor=1.0)
# to calcualte combinations
results1 = combination1.solve(ss)
for k, ss in results1.items():
    if k == 'combination':
         results1[k].show_reaction_force(show=True)
         results1[k].show_bending_moment(show=True)
         results1[k].show_displacement(show=True)
         results1[k].show_axial_force(show=True)
```

```
File "E:/main/fem_analysis/l_profile.py", line 72, in l_profile_loads
    results1[k].show_reaction_force(show=True)
  File "E:\models\fem_model\fem\system.py", line 910, in show_reaction_force
    return self.plotter.reaction_force(figsize, verbosity, scale, offset, show)
  File "E:\models\fem_model\fem\plotter\mpl.py", line 669, in reaction_force
    max_force = max(
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

Comment: Please [edit] to include the full traceback.

Comment: @tripleee It was already there, but not obvious cause it was in the same preformatted block as the code. i fixed it.